# Парсинг цен с сайта gruzivagon.ru

Tags: c#, веб-скрейпинг

Пытаюсь парсить цены со страницы 
http://gruzivagon.ru/index.php/component/ads?cat=8&p=0

Меня интересуют цены только на полувагоны. Для выбора этой категории нужно открыть фильтр и вручную выбрать нужную категорию ("Полувагоны"). При этом url не изменится, а выдача заменится на 20-30 строк нужных мне строк (при том что изначально, до работы с фильтром, выдача содержит лишь 1-2 строк по полувагонам).

Не могу понять, откуда загружаются данные. В хроме раздел Network, обычно показывающий, куда страница обращается за подгружаемыми данными, в данном случае никакие новые url не отображает. В коде страницы также изначально (до работы с фильтром) нужные мне 20-30 строк не присутствуют. Пытался менять параметр &p=0 в ссылке, но это тоже ни к чему не привело.

Как можно программно получить данные по нужной мне категории вагонов? Вариант симуляции открытия страницы в браузере не рассматриваю. Идеально было бы, например, определить ссылку на json массив с данными. Заранее спасибо.

Программирую на C#, но думаю это принципиальной разницы не имеет.

Comment: Скорее всего, работает ajax. Никакими url запросами вы эту информацию не получите. Только парсинг через selenium web driver, хотите вы этого или нет.

Comment: Сайт, по ходу, сделан на Джумле. Если подобрать url типа ...&show=all, то задача решена: выводится полный список всего, а потом уже легко отобрать полувагоны. Однако компонент, скорее всего, самописный, и подбор будет непрост, если вообще возможен. Запрос передается в /components/com_ads/st.php, а там уже происходит формирование вывода.